# Indian national transiting through heathrow from Paris

Tags: visas, transit, london

BA 1536 24APR DFW(Dallas)->CDG(Paris) HK1  1505  #0735

BA 307 09MAY CDG(Paris)->LHR(London) HK1  1030   1050

BA 119 09MAY LHR(London)->BLR(Bangalore) HK1  1420  #0445

I have a flight which originates from Dallas, goes to Paris, and from Paris gets to Bangalore via London. The transit time is less than 3 hours and I will not have any check-in luggage (so no border control?). As per my understanding I should be exempt since I have a valid US visa. https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no

But my travel agent says I need a transit visa for London. Does anybody know the updated rules for transit?

Comment: It seems like your real question is "how can I convince my travel agent that I don't need a transit visa because I hold a valid US visa?"